# Remove default OpenStreetMap tile layer in Leaflet - Folium?

Tags: python, leaflet, openstreetmap, visualisation, folium

I have multiple maps in my Folium map (map1 and map2) however, I see OpenStreetMap as the default option. I want to remove the OSM option altogether and keep just my two custom layers. If I set `tiles` to `None` in `folium.Map`, then I see nothing at all.

How do I resolve this?

```
m = folium.Map(location = location, zoom_start=14, control_scale = True, tiles = None)
marker_cluster = MarkerCluster(name = "example").add_to(m)

folium.TileLayer('URL', name = "MAP1", attr = "MAP1").add_to(m)
folium.TileLayer('URL', name = 'MAP2', attr = 'MAP2').add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

Comment: Try setting tiles to `None` with `tiles = 'None'`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a cross-post from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69460906/leaflet-folium-remove-openstreetmap

Comment: @TomazicM this gives me an error: "Custom tiles must have an attribution"